# PHP and REST API - Retrieving Company Updates

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm actually working on displaying my company updates as a feed on my website.

I've created an App on LinkedIn and I'm able to get my security token and list info related to my profile by using the : **"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/ME"**.

However, when I'm trying to retrieve my company updates using a GET call on : **"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/".$company_id."/updates"**. I'm getting a :

**"Member does not have permission to get company."** in the HTTP response message.

Configuration set :

- I'm correctly listed as Admin on my company's page
- "rw_company_admin" is enabled on my LinkedIn App
- My App status is set to "Live"
- My company ID is the correct one (I've double checked already)
- My token is properly issued and I'm correctly identified by the app

Here is the code I'm using in the PHP method to get the updates :

```html
public function getCompanyUpdates($company_id, $start=0,$count = 20){
  if(!$company_id)return false;
  $params['url'] = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/".$company_id."/updates";
  $params['method']='get';
  $params['args']['format']='json';
  if($start != 0 )$params['args']['start']=$start;
  if($count != 0 )$params['args']['count']=$count;
  $params['args']['event-type']='status-update';
  $result =  $this->makeRequest($params);
  return json_decode($result,true);
 }
```

I'm probably missing a step somewhere, but I've no idea where..

In advance, thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Here is an additional info, I'm also passing the scopes during the "getAuthorizeUrl" with this code : 

  `$scope = array('rw_company_admin','r_basicprofile','r_emailaddress','w_share');
        $connect_link = $LIOAuth->getAuthorizeUrl($client_id,$redirect_url,$scope);`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error some weeks ago, but forgot to post the answer that fixes the issue.

My errors :
- At first, I forgot to pass the scope while requesting the Token
- After fixing this, I forgot to re-issue a new Token to get the scope applied

To conclude, it was just an oversight from me.

However, the LinkedIn API is a bit shitty, as it requires to refresh the Token periodically. It should be simplified when we only want to list Public updates that everyone can access.

Cheers

Comment: which scope was missing ?